# Rails with randomised planks

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

I'm trying to generate lots of rails using "animation nodes" and after "googling" I have something like this on the screen. But I have one problem, I don't know how to use more than one object for this crosswise planks.

Right now I have connected "Object Instancer" , how can I add multiple object instancer with random placing of this planks?

In other words I'm looking for a methods to duplicate randomly 3 elements along the curve.

Best!

[image]

Comment: let's tag @OmarAhmad here...

Comment: Please use the `animation-nodes` tag for questions related to Animation Nodes. Can you tell me exactly what you expect the output to be? Maybe place some of them by hand so that I can see the result you are after.

Comment: I can't use my computer right now but it's feiry simple to describe. I'm looking for method to duplicate or instance 3 objects along the curve in random order. Right now I have only one plank connected to rails but it's will be cool to use more different shapes of them for more variety look of train rails.

Ps. Animation-node tag submitted ;)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of instancing a single object, create a number of empty objects using the *Object Instancer Node* with the *Copy From Source* option disabled. Then get a list of all objects that has the meshes you want, generate a random list from them using the *Random List Node* and copy the data from the objects in this list to the empty objects you created using the *Copy Object Data Node*.

[image: Node Tree]